# IPhone app submission to applestore

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am going to submit updated version of my existing app on apple store.I am not sure when i will submit my new version for approval than in that duration my running app on apple store will be removed or remain.

Plz help .

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, not does it appear to contain a question.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your app then it takes 10 days to accept during this period your running app
is not remove. but when your updated version is accept then your previous version replace by new one.

Comment: when my new version is in approval process my app current version users are able to download?